# GetGlobalResourceObject not working in page with <%@ Page Async="true" %>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

GetGlobalResourceObject not working in page with <%@ Page Async="true" %>. So translation on all html tags not working. How to make it work.

I am using .NET 4.5. My code looks like

```
<div class="row" style="color:red;">

    <b><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","Label_ImportantPoints") %>:</b>
    <ul>
        <%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","Label_Info") %>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding an async method and await that instead of using this approach? [This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) might help you.

Comment: You mean to translate HTML controls, I need to add  async method ? How to do it?

Comment: Please refer the MSDN article I posted in my original comment.

Comment: You may need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) if you data contains special characters.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng, Not sure why I need this. My basic issue is translation which is not working because of Async attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by translation?  If you color is a hex/binary number you have to use special characters to include the number in the request/response.  See the Wiki link.